Bitcoin Core wallet.dat keys details
I have python script to dump wallet.dat details to json+hex file. It operates with bsddb3 library. There are keys and values. They can be divided into:

addresses
keys (private keys?)
transactions
metadata

depending on the first byte.
I have: 02, 03, 05, 07, 09, 0a, 0c, 12 as the first bytes for all keys in some encrypted wallet.
What does these first bytes mean and how should I divide types of keys into groups by this first byte?

They correspond to specific record types commonly found in older legacy wallet, specificaly:
0x02: KEY - Private key entries (in very old or unencrypted wallets, these store the pubkey and corresponding private key).

0x03: WKEY - An older, now-deprecated record type related to wallet keys. It was used in very early wallet versions and isn’t typically seen in modern wallets.

0x05: NAME - Address book entries (the "label" or "name" associated with a particular Bitcoin address).

0x07: POOL - Keypool entries (pre-generated addresses/keys waiting to be used).

0x09: ACC - Account records (from older wallet versions that supported accounts, now deprecated).

0x0a: ACENTRY - Account entry records, detailing transactions or balances associated with named accounts (also deprecated).

0x0c: CSCRIPT - Storing redeem scripts (used for P2SH addresses or other special script conditions).

0x12: WTX (Transaction) - Full transaction records relevant to the wallet’s balance and history.

Grouping by Record Type:

Keys (private keys): Look for 0x02 (and sometimes 0x03 in very old wallets).

Address-related metadata: 0x05 (NAME) stores address labels.

Keypool and Account Info: 0x07 (POOL) and 0x09/0x0a (ACC/ACENTRY) for pre-HD, account-based workflows.

Scripts: 0x0c (CSCRIPT) for redeem scripts.

Transactions: 0x12 (WTX) for recorded wallet transactions.

For more information you can check this old python script that give information about wallet.dat file, you can also look into the source code
https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet
